# How to play 2 different videos based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a preview of a website right now and am wondering how to play 2 different videos depending on whether the user is on mobile or desktop.

The reason is that I have 2 videos formatted properly for desktop and mobile and can't seem to figure out how to hide one and display the other based on screen size.

I have looked into media queries but wouldn't know where to start with them.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.innerWidth; // returns the width in pixels of the window
```

so you could use something like:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 425) {
    // display video for desktop
} else {
    // display video for mobile
}
```